# cancel Windows authentication prompt on chrome through selenium

Tags: selenium, authentication, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to write a selenium test which :

- Connect to a website (which prompt an authentication window)
- Click on "cancel" of the authentication window
- Do some test stuffs...

But my problem is that : **I am not able to cancel the authentication step**.

My test should not depend on the environment (I don't want to change the Windows registry keys)

I found this chromium command "--auth-server-whitelist=..." that automatically fills and submit this prompt and I am looking for something that would always refuse the authentication.

Any Ideas ? Suggestions of better ways ?

Comment: Why do you want to `cancel the authentication step`? What is your business requirement? Is it a Basic Authentication popup?

Comment: I want to cancel this authentication windows because I want to create a robot/selenium test on an existing application, which is using this kind of authentication, **but** has a fallback in a usual (web "login" page) authentication way and I'm not able to fill this window with different users using robot/selenium (rather than my actual Windows user). 

So my fallback is to be able to cancel this authentication step to get the usual login form and fill it thanks to selenium